# Generating A Single Digit Number Random time

Tags: php, random, numbers

I need to generate a single number random time by php.

Like i want to generate  0  random time

result could b like

0000
or
0000000000
or
0000000000000000

any one can help?

Answer (score 5):

```
str_repeat('0', mt_rand(1, 10))
```

Generates a string between 1 and 10 characters long.

Comment: Uhm... by putting `echo` in front of it.